# While creating a REST API in node, How can I stream http response from a request made to an external website to the original api call?

Tags: node.js, api, rest, http, http-streaming

So, I am creating a REST API using node and I have to create a route.
Purpose of the route: Act as a proxy server and make a call to a different external website and return the response it gets to the original request.
So far, I have the following code and it works:

```
app.post('/v1/something/:_id/proxy',
    function(req, res, next) {
        // Basically make a request call to some external website and return
        // the response I get from that as my own response
        var opts = {/*json containing proper uri, mehtod and json*/}
        request(opts, function (error, responseNS, b) {
            if(error) return callback(error)
            if(!responseNS) return callback(new Error('!response'))

            return res.json(responseNS.body)
        })
    }
)
```

My question is, how can I stream this http response that I am getting from the external website. By that, I mean that I want to get the response as a stream and keep returning it as soon as it comes in chunks.
Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to return a chunk once it was recieved from request to external website?

Comment: You should not use the json flag in the options if you want to pipe it through, since you shouldn't care about the content in this case. That flag implicitly activates JSON deserialization, that would require a complete buffer of the response in order to deserialize it.

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr : Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pipe the incoming response from an external source straight to a response that your app sends to the browser, like this:

```
app.post('/v1/something/:_id/proxy',
function(req, res, next) {
    // Basically make a request call to some external website and return
    // the response I get from that as my own response
    var opts = {/*json containing proper uri, mehtod and json*/}
    request(opts, function (error, responseNS, b) {
        if(error) return callback(error)
        if(!responseNS) return callback(new Error('!response'))

        return res.json(responseNS.body)
    }).pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: Just one question, does 'pipe' solve the purpose of sending the chunks of response as soon as we receive it?

Answer (score 1):

With request you can directly pipe incoming response to either file stream, to other requests or to the response that your api sends to the browser. Like

```
function (req, res, next) {
    request
      .get('http://example.com/doodle.png')
      .pipe(res)    
}
```

Similary in your case just pipe to response.

```
app.post('/v1/something/:_id/proxy',
    function(req, res, next) {
        // Basically make a request call to some external website and return
        // the response I get from that as my own response
        var opts = {/*json containing proper uri, mehtod and json*/}
        request(opts, function (error, responseNS, b) {
            if(error) return callback(error)
            if(!responseNS) return callback(new Error('!response'))
        }).pipe(res);
    }
)
```